# Cutting big string into objects

Tags: php, regex

I have a huge string from a server, and I want each line as an object (for later foreach loop).

This is part of the string:

```
1535;;34290;;teaserbanner_881.jpg;;Not allowed;;closed;;;;closed;;
1535;;34291;;teaserbanner_8832.jpg;;Not allowed;;closed;;;;closed;;
1379;;31912;;teaserbanner_844.jpg;;Allowed;;open;;;;open;;
1379;;31913;;teaserbanner_8422.jpg;;allowed;;closed;;;;closed;;
```

The only thing that stays the same for each line is the "closing tags"
only two options:

1. ;;closed;;;;closed;;
2. ;;open;;;;open;;

I was thinking that it should be the needle for explode or some regex...

The final output should be:

```
element[0]  1535;;34290;;teaserbanner_881.jpg;;Not allowed;;closed;;;;closed;;
element[1]  1535;;34291;;teaserbanner_8832.jpg;;Not allowed;;closed;;;;closed;;
element[2]  1379;;31912;;teaserbanner_844.jpg;;Allowed;;open;;;;open;;
element[3]  1379;;31913;;teaserbanner_8422.jpg;;allowed;;closed;;;;closed;;
```

The string doesn't come in "lines" it is one big line.

Comment: Do you mean each line as an array element?

Comment: Is there a carriage return after each line that comes from the server?

Comment: yes, sorry i am new in php...

Comment: @user2706762 You mean Yes at Mark or Yes at user2793390?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [**`preg_match_all function`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php):

```
$s = <<< EOF
1535;;34290;;teaserbanner_881.jpg;;Not allowed;;closed;;;;closed;;
1535;;34291;;teaserbanner_8832.jpg;;Not allowed;;closed;;;;closed;;
1379;;31912;;teaserbanner_844.jpg;;Allowed;;open;;;;open;;
1379;;31913;;teaserbanner_8422.jpg;;allowed;;closed;;;;closed;;
EOF;

if (preg_match_all('~(.*?;;(open|closed);{4}\2;;)~', $s, $arr))
   print_r($arr[1]);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1535;;34290;;teaserbanner_881.jpg;;Not allowed;;closed;;;;closed;;
    [1] => 1535;;34291;;teaserbanner_8832.jpg;;Not allowed;;closed;;;;closed;;
    [2] => 1379;;31912;;teaserbanner_844.jpg;;Allowed;;open;;;;open;;
    [3] => 1379;;31913;;teaserbanner_8422.jpg;;allowed;;closed;;;;closed;;
)
```

Comment: thanks but the string doesnt come in lines, it is one big line.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at [split](http://php.net/manual/de/function.split.php). `split("\n", $string)` will give you an array, where each entry is one line of the string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) for this:-

```
$lines = file('path/to/file');
foreach($lines as $line){
    //do something with $line
}
```

$lines is an array with each element representing a line in the file so that

```
var_dump($lines);
```

Would give something like:-

```
array (size=4)
  0 => string '1535;;34290;;teaserbanner_881.jpg;;Not allowed;;closed;;;;closed;;' (length=68)
  1 => string '1535;;34291;;teaserbanner_8832.jpg;;Not allowed;;closed;;;;closed;;    ' (length=69)
  2 => string '1379;;31912;;teaserbanner_844.jpg;;Allowed;;open;;;;open;;    ' (length=60)
  3 => string '1379;;31913;;teaserbanner_8422.jpg;;allowed;;closed;;;;closed;;' length=63)
```

Comment: thanks but the string doesnt come in lines, it is one big line.

Comment: Ah, OK, that's not what you show in your question. So how do you determine where you will split it?

Comment: ;;closed;;;;closed;; or ;;open;;;;open;;

Answer (score 1):

Try using `preg_split`:

```
$array = preg_split('/(?<=;;closed;;;;closed;;|;;open;;;;open;;)(?!$)/', $string)
```

`(?<=;;closed;;;;closed;;|;;open;;;;open;;)` makes sure there are the closing tags before the point of splitting and `(?!$)` makes sure the string isn't split at the end.

[viper7 demo](http://viper-7.com/KDYYIQ)

Answer (score 0):

**What does huge mean?**

`exploding()` something actually huge will deplete your PHP memory.

**You need to parse it old school**, char by char and add them to a bucket. When your condition is met *(like the 5th `;` or 10th `;` or whatever...)*, consider the bucket a proper object and handle it. But don't store it. Push it to a file, a DB or something.

**If things are not that huge**, use a `regular expression` with an *'object'* format. Like:

```
// keep duplicating the (.*?);; until you reach your number of columns.
preg_match_all '~(.*?);;(.*?);;(.*?);;(.*?);;(.*?);;~s' // pseudo-code :)
```

And this will break it all into objects and properties. Which you can iterate and use.